# gcloud --format concatenate string

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was thinking if it is possible to concatenate a string using *gcloud* --format

For example:

```
gcloud redis instances describe redis1 --region us-central1 --format "redis://value(host):value(port)"
```

which results on `redis://10.104.154.107:6379`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The format requires a valid key word (text, json,...). Here value() return only the value of the list of fields (comma separated).

To achieve what you want, it's much longer

```
echo "redis://$(gcloud redis instances describe redis1 --region us-central1 --format value(host))\
:$(gcloud redis instances describe redis1 --region us-central1 --format value(port))"
```

Comment: Thanks. As I suspected. I ended as you answered